# Yii2 UploadImageBehavior. How to remove file?

Tags: yii, yii2, image-uploading

I have a problem with UploadImageBehavior.

I need to create simple button on frontend part that allow me to remove image (user avatar) after model save.
Actually i know how to do it with `unlink`, but i absolutely don't understand how to do that via behaviour.

I have next code in rules:

`[['avatar'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg'],`

So Yii just ignore me, if i try to pass `null` to my avatar property.

Thx )

Answer (score 0):

Just create a method to your model class that does the unlinking, sets the file attribute in your model to null and saves the model.

```
public function removeAvatar() {
    $transaction = $this->getDb()->beginTransaction();
    try {
        // If this is a new record throw an Exception because no file has been uploaded yet
        if($this->isNewRecord) {
           throw new \Exception("Can't delete file of new record");
        }

        // Set the attribute avatar to null
        $this->avatar = null;

        // Try to save the record. If we can't then throw an Exception
        if(!$this->save()) {
            throw new \Exception("Couldn't save the model");
        }

        // Try to delete the file. If we can't then throw an Exception
        if(!unlink(Yii::getAlias('@app/path/to/your/file.something')) {
            throw new \Exception("Couldn't delete the file");
        }

        $transaction->commit();
        return true;
    }
    catch(\Exception $e) {
        $transaction->rollback();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below works for me:

```
unlink(getcwd().'/uploads/'.$model->file_id.'/'.$fileModel->file_name.$fileModel->extension);
```

getcwd() gets the current working directory. The docs for it are [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)